# Unexpected behavior from Part

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Commonly, there are many issues faced by me when using the "Parts" function. In particular, the function itself is not behaving in a manner outlined in the manual.

One frustrating instances as it is right now is this:

[image]

The dimensions as outlined by Mathematica is {52,2}.

Now,

[image]

Which is not correct given that Mathematica has already regconised the Matrix as having 52 x 2 dimensions.

What I want is the entirety of the second column vector.

I have a strong suspicion that the manual is outdated.
[enter link description here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetPartsOfAMatrix.html)
I've tested the function

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DId you take the dimensions of `MatrixForm`?  We can't text your code as you haven't given it, but I've never encountered a problem like this with `[[]]`, so the problem probably lies with your data or code.

Comment: I will post that soon. But look at my edited post. There is mismatch with the examples in Mathematica manual and the results one gets when executing that same example from the manual itself.

Comment: @Feyre I did and the result is evaluates to "1" which is a scalar so something is wrong somewhere. The MatrixForm function should not be changing anything.

Comment: No it isn't, you're taking the part of a `MatrixForm[]`, the first part of which is the Matrix. Don't define your matrix as `...something...//MatrixForm`. You can get the expected result by `[[1,(part you want]]` such as `[[1,All,1]]` in your list of states.

Comment: `MatrixForm` is a wrapper used for display purposes. It does not mean that it somehow tells MMA that the object is a matrix. Your matrix is `mat`. Period.

Comment: @corey979 This explains then why the mathematical structure is not preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think your matrix has the form

```
m1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 5}]
```

> `{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}}`

and, therefore, that you should get

```
m1[[All, 1]]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

but it really has the form

```
m2 = {m1}
```

Evaluating

```
m2[[All, 1]]
```

gives

> `{{1, 1}}`

which is analogous to what you are experiencing.